# Jenkins pipeline job, to run docker, not work

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline

**Help me?  I have a project in Jenkins (pipeline), this project aims to, run a cucumber tests with docker.**

***Note: The tests are all on a local machine, only for study. SO: Windows 7**

**But, when i run the project with Jenkins, return this error:***

```
java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:249)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:218)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:929)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:449)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:460)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.impl.RegistryKeyMaterialFactory.materialize(RegistryKeyMaterialFactory.java:72)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.AbstractEndpointStepExecution.start(AbstractEndpointStepExecution.java:45)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:229)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:153)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker": CreateProcess error=2, O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:249)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:218)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:929)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:449)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:460)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.impl.RegistryKeyMaterialFactory.materialize(RegistryKeyMaterialFactory.java:72)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.AbstractEndpointStepExecution.start(AbstractEndpointStepExecution.java:45)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:229)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:153)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker.withRegistry(jar:file:/C:/Jenkins/plugins/docker-workflow/WEB-INF/lib/docker-workflow.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/Docker.groovy:40)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor328.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:46)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$101(SandboxContinuable.java:34)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.lambda$run0$0(SandboxContinuable.java:59)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:58)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:332)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Finished: FAILURE
```

**"Cannot run program "docker"**

**After several searches, most indicate as a result, install the docker on the local machine as it is for her that the jenkins will look at. However my machine already has docker, and it works normally, as output from the command below**

```
$ docker info
Containers: 131
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 130
Images: 188
Server Version: 18.05.0-ce
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 427
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 773c489c9c1b21a6d78b5c538cd395416ec50f88
runc version: 4fc53a81fb7c994640722ac585fa9ca548971871
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.9.93-boot2docker
Operating System: Boot2Docker 18.05.0-ce (TCL 8.2.1); HEAD : b5d6989 - Thu May 10 16:35:28 UTC 2018
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 995.6MiB
Name: default
ID: A3OP:HSIS:MQOH:NX66:6VWA:4KB7:SPNZ:XPOP:2RWO:IBCR:4QMO:GJMM
Docker Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
 provider=virtualbox
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

**Anyone have any idea what's going on?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if Jenkins is able to execute Docker.
create a test job and In "Build" execute shell with cmd "Docker Version".
if you got proper response then it is fine and some issue with your job. 
if not, then check docker configuration in jenkins.

Edited:-
You can set Environment Path variable(window) from jenkins.// go to manage jenkins --> configure system -> Global Properties --> check on Environment variable -> Name = DOCKER_PATH, Value= {{Docker installation path on window}}\bin --> add other variable --> Name=Path, Value=%Path%;%DOCKER_PATH%--> Save... Restart jenkins and try again...

Comment: The return:

Construindo no workspace C:\Jenkins\workspace\teste_doc_func
[teste_doc_func] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins4923908087030268188.bat

C:\Jenkins\workspace\teste_doc_func>docker -v 
'docker' nÆo ‚ reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa oper vel ou um arquivo em lotes.

C:\Jenkins\workspace\teste_doc_func>exit 9009 
Build step 'Executar no comando do Windows' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

 but de configure docker is Ok, when i run in CMD, function.

Comment: i am not able to understand the error as it is not in English. But seems like "docker -v" failed in CMD from jenkins.//// seems like you have to set docker path in windows env PATH variable on windows, once done then restart the jenkins. You can verify PATH variable value same as "docker -v" cmd in test job.

Comment: You can set Environment Path variable from jenkins also.// go to manage jenkins --> configure system -> Global Properties --> check on Environment variable -> Name = DOCKER_PATH, Value= {{Docker installation path on window}}\bin --> add other variable --> Name=Path, Value=%Path%;%DOCKER_PATH%--> Save... Restart jenkins and try again...

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the problem.
Now function ok.